# Why proof by contradiction here?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

In the book [How to prove it, page 102](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf), the following problem is given:

`Suppose A, B, and C are sets, A \ B ⊆ C, and x is anything at all.
If x ∈ A \ C then x ∈ B.`

I can prove it the following manner:

x ∈ A \ C $\rightarrow$ (x ∈ A $\wedge$ x not ∈ C)

It is given that

A \ B ⊆ C

x not ∈ C => x not ∈ A \ B

x not ∈ A \ B can be expressed as:

$\neg$ (x ∈ A $\wedge$ x not ∈ B) = (x not ∈ A $\vee$ x ∈ B)

by conditional law:

(x not ∈ A $\vee$ x ∈ B) = (x ∈ A $\rightarrow$  x ∈ B).

It is given that x ∈ A hence x ∈ B.

But the proof is provided by contradiction as follows:

`Proof. Suppose x ∈ A \ C. This means that x ∈ A and x not ∈ C. 
Suppose x not ∈ B.
Then x ∈ A \ B, so since A \ B ⊆ C, x ∈ C. But this contradicts the fact that
x not ∈ C. Therefore x ∈ B. Thus, if x ∈ A \ C then x ∈ B.`

Why is proof by contradiction <del>necessary</del> preferred here? Is not the first proof more intuitive and enough?

Comment: "$x$ is anything at all"? I'd like to have a chat with the author...

Comment: What's your justification of the line that begins "but we know"?

Comment: @Y.Forman x ∈ A, and x not ∈ A \ B can only be true if $\rightarrow$ x ∈ B ?

Comment: @Ngm Can you justify that claim? It's the least self-evident step of your proof.

Comment: I read the linked page. It doesn't state anywhere, that a proof by contradiction is neccessary it just happens that this is the presented proof. This is motivated by "Lacking anything else to do, we try proof by contradiction"

Comment: @Y.Forman: added the expansion

Comment: @klirk : Yes it did not claim that, but the author uses that as the first approach.

Comment: The author provides a reason for doing so. Its just the first he can think of. It seems like your edit messed something up, i think the line "x ∈ A, and x not ∈ A \ B can only be true if → x ∈ B" is redundant. By the way, did my answer help you or are there any uncertainties left?

Comment: @Ngm Looks good now. I'd say the advantage of the author's proof over yours is that yours involves more logical manipulations. On the other hand, the author's proof needs contradiction, while yours doesn't. At this point, I'd agree with klirk that "Which one is more intuitive is up to personal taste."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Which one is more intuitive is up to personal taste.

I like the proof by contradiction, as it allows to dircectly use the assumption $A\setminus B \subset C$.

In comparison, your direct proof assumes $x\in A\setminus C$. So in order to use the assumption, you have to negate it first, i.e. you look at the complements $C^c\subset (A \setminus B)^c$.

As a remark to your proof: Even though you wrote in the beginning that the goal is to prove  `x ∈ A \ C → (x ∈ A ∧ x not ∈ C)`, during the proof you should make clear that you consider an $x \in A\setminus C$.